# SQL Server - How to delete the view statement after creating view in database

Tags: sql, sql-server

We can use Encription to hide the view statement, like

```
CREATE VIEW TestTable
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
SELECT *
FROM employees
```

In this way, we cannot find the scripts for creating view from 'Script view as -> Create to '.
Except for Encryption, is there any way to directly drop the view statement while creating view table?

For instance, after creating a view table, people can find the script of how the view is created by selecting 'Script view as -> Create to'. I mean we can use Encryption to hide the database code, but how to directly delete those database code of view statement. And the `select * from TestTable` should not be affected.

Comment: to drop view use `DROP VIEW <view_name>;`

Comment: *"is there any way to directly drop the view statement while creating view table?"* Do you still want the view to be available/usable after this has been done? Because I think you've misunderstood what a view is. It isn't a table, it's a dynamic dataset based on underlying data.

Comment: maybe you can explain what are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: I don't recommend you to bother with encryption. It is easily reversible, you cannot completely hide your database code.

Comment: Hi Roger, does this mean we don't have any options to hide the database codes while creating view? Maybe can create a new table, and create view from that table? this can hide all the database code?

Comment: Your edit since my last comment includes the phrase *after creating a view table* which again implies that you think that creating a view creates a physical table of data. It doesn't. The view **is** just the view *definition*: a logical perspective of other data in the database, hence the name "view". If you remove the *definition* of the view, the view no longer exists.

Comment: Note that encryption of a view is only obfuscation. You could of course create a table to materialize the results of the query instead of using a view but the data will be static and not reflect changes to the source data after creation.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you need revoke view DEFINITION ,  you may try like below

```
USE your_database;  
REVOKE VIEW DEFINITION FROM user_name CASCADE;  
GO
```

Comment: This will delete all the views, How can we drop the view statement for creating view table and keep the views for selecting?

Comment: @user3651247 do you want drop and recreate ? not clear what your expectation . can you please clear a bit more

Comment: I mean to delete the view statement from creating. so that ppl cannot find the script of the view from 'Script view as -> Create to '. Is there anyway  to do it?  The way you suggest is to delete all the view table.

Comment: @user3651247 "This will delete all the views" - no, it will delete only one view, `TestTable` in this particular case.

Comment: @user3651247 i think you want Revokes permissions to create view on your database  right?

Comment: @user3651247 i think you want to revoke view DEFINITION from a particular user i edited my answer you can try

Comment: Now I got it. I think the way you are doing now is just limit some particular users access to the view definition. It looks like we cannot hide the definitions. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Hi @user3651247, that's a typo error. of course drop view viewTable will only drop 'viewTable'. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hide the definitions from DBAs/SA/DBO but you can put permissions to limit access.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a script of Encrypted View on SQL Server following the way of

[image]

So your code that forms the View's SELECT query is safe

Of course there are third party tools used to [decrypt encrypted views](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-tools/sql-server-tool-decrypt-encrypted-stored-procedures.aspx) source code on SQL Server.

So in fact, there is not a way of reading the source code explicitely for an encrypted object on SSMS

By the way, "DROP VIEW viewname" will only delete the targeted SQL object
There is not a command to drop all views in one statement like "drop views", etc.